# Redirecting a View to another View in Django Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, redirect, django-views

How does one redirect from one View to another (next-going one):

```
class FooView(TemplateView):
  template_name 'foo.html'

  def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect(BarView)
    # return redirect(BarView.as_view()) ???

class BarView(TemplateView):
  template_name 'bar.html'
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Give the URL pattern itself a name in your urls.py:

```
url('/bar/', BarView.as_view(), name='bar')
```

and just pass it to redirect:

```
return redirect('bar')
```

Comment: This looks good. The previous version of the views.py had foo() and bar() as functions. And foo() was redirecting to bar and passing id parameter like this: redirect(bar, id). Trying to use url('bar') doesn't work unfortunately, looks like I made mistake somewhere.

Comment: What if it has some data afterward that you need to pass in the url, like bar/923784983479 ?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) for that, if you've given the view a name in `urls.py`.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
return redirect('some-view-name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give **the view name "bar"** to the path in **"myapp/urls.py"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/urls.py"

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = "myapp"

urlpatterns = [                 # This is view name
    path('bar/', views.BarView, name="bar")
]
```

Then, you need **the conbination of the app name "myapp", colon ":" and the view name "bar"** as shown below. In addition, you don't need to import **the view "bar"** in **"myapp/views.py"**:

```py
# "myapp/views.py"

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def FooView(request):
                    # Here
    return redirect("myapp:bar")

def BarView(request):
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', {})
```