# How to redirect to another app directory after loging in django?

Tags: django

I have two app directories in my django project named "visit" and "main". After Loging the user in through visit app, how do I change the app directory to another main i;e how to display templates from another app (excuse my english) ?

visit/views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import forms
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'visit/index.html', context=None)


def profile(request):   # I need to change directory form here
    return render(request, 'main/templates/main/profile.html')


def registration(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            formObj = form.cleaned_data
            username = formObj["username"]
            name = formObj["name"]
            email = formObj["email"]
            password = formObj["password"]
            if not (User.objects.filter(username=username).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()):
                User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
                user = authenticate(username=username, name=name, password=password)
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'visit/registration/register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: You're doing it correctly - either using `redirect` shortcut or the `HttpResponseRedirect`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071750/redirecting-a-view-to-another-view-in-django-python

Answer (score 1):

if you configured your urls to use namespaces you could do:

`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("appname:urlname"))`

otherwise you could simply reverse the url name:

`HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("urlname"))`

Answer (score 1):

First thing, you should make sure you have a base URL file in your settings.py which can access the urls from all your apps.

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'your_main_app.urls'
```

Then, in your main urls.py you can collect all the urls from each app

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^some_path/', include('some_app.urls')),
    url(r'^another_path/', include('some_other_app.urls')),
    ...,
]
```

Make sure you have also set the template directory structure.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
```

]

This allows your project to look through each app for a templates folder. You can then set up all your templates in your directory as

```
main_project_directory
    |--visit
        |--templates
           |--visit
              |--index.html
    |--main
        |--templates
           |--main
              |--profile.html
```

Then, each time you go to reference a template - you may call them as

```
template_name='app_name/template_name.html'
```

in your case

```
def profile(request):  
    return render(request, 'main/profile.html')
```

so you avoid having the same template structure twice, and it's a bit easier to call/keep track of which template is being used.