# What is the order for django visit urls.py

Tags: python, django

everyone,

I am pretty new to Django. 
I notice that Django visit app.urls before visit mysite.urls.

I have mysite.urls as follow (simplified)

```
# mysite.urls

    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('app', include('app.urls'))
```

To my understanding, when visit http://127.0.0.1:8000/, it should first reach index page.

```
Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

login/ [name='login']
register/ [name='register']

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

Seems that Django went to app.urls directly without went to mysite.urls first.

What could be the issue here?

---

Content of my two urls file

mysite.url

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from mapApp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('app', include('mapApp.urls'))
]
```

app.urls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('resetPassword/', views.reset_password, name='resetPassword'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

---

Error message

I notice that seems the whole mysite.urls file is ignored. Django goes for my "mapAPP.urls" only

[image]

---

The structure of my file folder

[image]

Comment: Is your **`app.urls`** and **`mysite.urls`** are different?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu different, mysite.urls comes from startproject, app.urls comes from startapp

Comment: Can you add both modules to the question?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Hi, I attached the content of two files above, hope this is the module you mentioned :P

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Can you add a screenshot of it or to share the whole Traceback if possible?

Comment: How many urls do you have? Can you update the files hierarchy of your dir please.

Comment: @AzyCrw4282, sorry, thought it was just a small issue. I have attached the files hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easiest solution:** set `ROOT_URLCONF` in `settings.py` to the app's urls you want. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124076/6505847) for a good explanation.

Django visits `urls.py` app by app. You seem to have two apps in your project `mysite` and `mapApp` and Django will simply look for the urls that you've defined.

It starts with `mapApp` urls.py and checks for any patterns

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('resetPassword/', views.reset_password, name='resetPassword'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout')
]
```

The pattern  `http://127.0.0.1:8000/,` doesnt match and hence it fails and returns `Page not found` error. To solve this you can simply include `path('', views.index, name='index'),` in urls.py in `mapApp`. Or you can include the mysite urls in mapApp.

For example, in `app.urls`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path('resetPassword/', views.reset_password, name='resetPassword'),
    path('logout', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('', include('mysite.urls'))
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But what decides the order? Is it ordered alphabetically?

Comment: That's defined by `ROOT_URLCONF` in settings.py. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49124076/6505847) for a good explanation.